# How can I get the URL of a page, or run a function, when page errors out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I open a page using `window.location = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + trackUrl + '&client_id=5f9f5186993f64c91...';`

It throws an error (sometimes a 403, other times a 406—it seems random) and prevents the remaining code from running.

I can open the console and run the code I wanted to run before the page errors out.

```
testURL= location.href; 
var trackId = testURL.match(new RegExp('/tracks/' + "(.*)" + '.json?')); 
alert(trackId[1]);
```

For some reason, the original URL changes to another when I run it but it has the value I need. Try it.

When I run the `window.location` above the following will appear in the address bar: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/330724405.json?client_id=5f9f5186993f64c91...`

The value I need is the `330724405` in that URL.

**So, the value I need is there. How can I get it programmatically?**

PS The use case is for error handling of URLs that won't resolve on their own. This is not a an auth issue, specific bad URLs, or intentional disabling of the API. Here is a URL that resolves properly and returns the JSON (address bar changes too like the failures!) you can try to see a successful resolve: `http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/radioopensource/stuart-schwartz-on-hurricane-history-in-the-caribbean&client_id=5f9f5186993f64c91...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but could you use XMLHttpRequest() and regex the responseURL? Maybe scrub for this.status 403 or 406 and readyState.

```
var trackUrl = "https://soundcloud.com/shinedownofficial/it-all-adds-up";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + trackUrl + " + client_id=5f9f5186993f64c91b1bb5cf43fe4b08", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseURL);
    'you can put your regex query here... 
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks! The URL in the address bar doesn't change but code halts from a 406. The value is in the error message inside the console. So, no worko.

Comment: Ah, I changed to !== for both state and status and seems to work. I'm not gonna get too excited yet since it needs more testing. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I think 200 is only for successes.

Comment: @ ApolloSoftware Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! Your advice was exactly what I needed to move forward. I did revert and check for `readyState`.